# Can't access files on network drive using FS npm module nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a network drive mapped to X:\ and for some reason I cannot access the files in it using the FS module. I tried using fs.existsSync(file) and it returns that no files can be found but when I type out the path fs.existsSync('X:\path\to\file') it works fine. Both file and the string I hardcoded are exactly the same, so why is fs returning different results for both? I have to use the "file" variable because I am looping through an array of file paths to create them in my network drive if they do not exist. I have also accounted for the backslashes, and replaced them all with double backslashes so the string is not being escaped.

```
    //This does not work
    let modifiedfilePathToSiger = path.join('X:\\', filePathToSiger.slice(17));
    let mps = JSON.stringify(modifiedfilePathToSiger)
    //Remove double quotes from mps
    let file = mps.replace(/['"]+/g, '')   //Ex: file here = X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx
    
    let found = fs.existsSync(file);
    console.log(found) //Returns false

    //This does work
    let found = fs.existsSync('X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx');
    console.log(found) //Returns true
```

One other thing to note, if I type out the whole hardcoded path into fs.existsSync() it works fine and returns true, but if I copy and paste the path that is logged from the console, it returns false, albeit the exact same path... not 1 character is different.

Comment: Would verify file === 'X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx'?

Comment: Yup, I console.log the value of file and it returns the same exact path

Comment: Pardon for not being clear. `console.log(( file === 'X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx'))` and see if the output is `true`

Comment: The output is false which is weird because I logged typeOf(file) and it returned String.

Comment: Looks like when I log file variable it returns X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx but when I log the hardcoded string X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx it returns X:\Data\Aerial Photo.docx . How can this be fixed so that file returns the same as the hardcoded string?

Comment: The result of URIEncoding file is X:%5C%5CData%5C%5CAerial%C2%A0Photo.docx

Comment: You `JSON.stringify` it which escapes the backslashes.

Comment: I removed JSON.stringify and still get false

Comment: Same thing goes when I replace all backslashes with forward slashes, I get false. When I hardcode the string with forward slashes I get true

Comment: Another thing to add, when using mime.lookup() it is able to find the file in the network drive. Only the FS module is giving me problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like when I log file variable it returns X:\Data\Aerial Photo.docx but when I log the hardcoded string X:\Data\Aerial Photo.docx it returns X:\Data\Aerial Photo.docx

Make use of `.split` and [`path.win32`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_win32) then [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)

From Node REPL

```sh
> path = require('path').win32
<ref *1> {
  resolve: [Function: resolve],
  normalize: [Function: normalize],
  isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
  join: [Function: join],
  relative: [Function: relative],
  toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],
  dirname: [Function: dirname],
  basename: [Function: basename],
  extname: [Function: extname],
  format: [Function: bound _format],
  parse: [Function: parse],
  sep: '\\',
  delimiter: ';',
  win32: [Circular *1],
  posix: <ref *2> {
    resolve: [Function: resolve],
    normalize: [Function: normalize],
    isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
    join: [Function: join],
    relative: [Function: relative],
    toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],
    dirname: [Function: dirname],
    basename: [Function: basename],
    extname: [Function: extname],
    format: [Function: bound _format],
    parse: [Function: parse],
    sep: '/',
    delimiter: ':',
    win32: [Circular *1],
    posix: [Circular *2],
    _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
  },
  _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
}
> strArr = file.split('\\')
[ 'X:', 'Data', 'Aerial Photo.docx' ]
> path.join(strArr[0],strArr[1],strArr[2])
'X:\\Data\\Aerial Photo.docx'
>
```

it will take care of the slashes respective to environment

Comment: When I split file it returned the following array [ 'X:', '', 'Data', '', 'Aerial Photo.docx' ]
then I did path.join(strArr[0], strArr[2], strArr[4]) and tried fs.existsSync() with that path but still returned false ('X:/Data/Aerial Photo.docx')

Comment: Updated the answer, please make use of path.win32, https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_win32

Comment: Tried with path.win32, file.split(path.sep); fs.existssync still returns false.

Comment: Also for some reason it's returning [ 'X:', '', 'Data', '', 'Aerial Photo.docx' ] instead of [ 'X:', 'Data', 'Aerial Photo.docx' ]